# Module parse failed: Unexpected token. You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: reactjs, sigma.js

When I import Attributes from 'graphology-types' in my .jsx file, I get this error

import { Attributes } from 'graphology-types'

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphology-types/index.d.ts 11:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:5)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |  * Miscellaneous types.
  |  */

> type Attributes = {[name: string]: any};
> |
> | type GraphType = 'mixed' | 'directed' | 'undirected';

I am new in React. I think the problem is that the graphology-types/index.d.ts is a TypeScript file and I am using .jsx files. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using TypeScript, you don't need to import types in your code. `Attributes` is a TS type that has no meaning or purpose in JS code. You don't need it. I suspect you may be copying TS examples into your code? If so, you can modify those to strip away the types.

Unless you want your app to be strongly typed, but that's a decision you should make separate from encountering this, on its own merits.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I was using a TS example but I didn't understood 'Attributes' is a TS type! Thanks for pointing this out!